# how to push edittext up when keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

hello i have an xml in which i have 2 edittext and listview when i click on edittext keyboard will appear but edittext will hide i want to push them up when keyborad apprears i tried all solution but no one work in my case i did adjustpan and adjustresize both but cant achieve my task below is my xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scnanningscreen_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/onoff_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/qrcode_img"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_tabsstyle"
        android:visibility="invisible" 
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtscannerstatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/qrcode_img"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Scanner Status:"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtrunner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtrunner"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtrunner"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/qrcode_img"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/editbox_roundedcorner"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:minHeight="30dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtposition"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtposition"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtposition"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etxtrunner"
        android:background="@drawable/editbox_roundedcorner"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:minHeight="30dp" >
    </EditText>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="178dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/qrcode_img"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/onoff_switch" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/qrcameraPreview"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="178dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:background="@drawable/corner_shapr" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/campre_relative"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="178dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:background="@drawable/corner_shape_textview"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Switch ON to Scan QR Code"
            android:textColor="#adadad"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtscanningresultfound"
        style="@style/keyboard_textview_style"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtprevscannedresults"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtprevscannedresults"
        android:text="No runner found"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:visibility="gone" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_rl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtprevscannedresults"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adview_layout" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/scanning_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtstatuswindow"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/corner_shape_textview"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Enter Runner"
        android:textColor="#00b200"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtrunner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtscannerstatus"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtstatuswindow"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Runner:"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtposition"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtrunner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtrunner"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Position:"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtprevscannedresults"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtposition"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtposition"
        android:text="Previous Scanned Results:"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtqrcode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txtscannerstatus"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/etxtposition"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adview_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i did it but same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.ex.YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: i did adjustpan and adjust resize both its not working

Comment: <activity android:name="com.example.Screen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"></activity>

Comment: o its work after some changing in my class :) thankyou

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is in your activity in android manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden|adjustPan"" >   <!--add this-->
    </activity>
```

or

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/yourlayout" >
  <!-- Here add a header or whatever will not be scrolled. -->
</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/something" >
  <!-- Here add your edittexts or whatever will scroll. -->
</ScrollView>
```

---

But prefer the first approach....

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm facing the same problem. I also tried adjustpan and adjustresize (individually and together as well). After my tries I found that adjustpan (only) is working well for devices other than samsung devices.

@Ahsan Malik, on which device you are testing?

Comment: if you are using inputmethodmanager or call keyboard from any type getwindow in class etc remove them all and let android use default behaviour

Comment: Well adjustpan is working on my nexus 5. Is your solution works on samsung devices as well?

Comment: I followed the way you instructed and removed the inputmethodmanager samsung devices are not working as expected